# How to get wopi discovery in the host page

Tags: javascript, java, ms-wopi

I'm working on an Office integration for the web using WOPI and trying to get the WOPI action from discovery.

I know the dogfood/testing endpoint from where I can get the discovery. But I couldn't directly get it in my web app due to cross-origin issue as it is in a different domain.

Am I supposed to store the discovery in API and serve it to the web app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering for the readers.

I was checking with Microsoft Senior Program Manager, he confirmed that WOPI discovery is meant to be a server-server thing. We need to fetch the WOPI discovery in the API side and keep it in cache until the proof key validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about these [two discovery files](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_test_ship/environments.html#wopi-discovery-urls). It seems that they have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers set to `*`, so that shouldn't be the problem.

I quickly tried this and it seems to work fine:

```js
fetch('https://ffc-onenote.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(str => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

You can run it here: https://jsfiddle.net/rockyintel/ycrw293n/13/

Maybe one more question, is your domain added to the [WOPI domain allow list](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_test_ship/settings.html#allow-list)?

Comment: Yes you are right but when I hit the same url, I get 

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ffc-onenote.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery' from origin * has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute"

Comment: I got email from MS that my domains are added